# How to save the state of MutableList during screen rotation

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have a

```
var routepoints: MutableList<LatLng> = ArrayList()
```

and I want to save in

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("routepoints",routepoints)

}
```

But I get a message

Type mismatch.
   Required:
   ArrayList!
   Found:
   MutableList

How to put my list to outState?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really concern about saving data while screen orientation change then use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) otherwise you can set `android:configChanges` in `Manifest.xml` with this line your activity will not recreate(So, data remain same).

```
<activity
....
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
.... >
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way to convert from MutableList to java.util.ArrayList

```
outState.putParcelableArrayList("routepoints", java.util.ArrayList<latLong>(routepoints))
```

remember that the latLong class needs to extend (subclass) the class [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable)

Hope it helps!